# How to set conditional color in MPS context editor?

Tags: colors, properties, mps

As a newbee of MPS I try to set different colors for finished items within a small todo list. I have a boolean properties attribute "finished" and want to return the color values - but I cannot use a named color or the java Color class. Surely I forgot something - can anyone tell me what to do?

[image]

Thank you very much for any answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the constants defined in java.awt.Color. You need to import the java.awt@stub model first (Control + M).

Comment: That was it - thank you very much! I think I tries it with setting the java.awt@stub language as a "used language", not as a dependency. Maybe you can tell me a site the difference is explained in?

Comment: @Christian: This is a different question. Create a new question and share it with the community.